# What is the meaning of "My mind is not shot"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

I'm reading book and I found this sentence, but when I translated it I get meaning something like "My mind not shot with gun".

What's this sentence mean?

The context is:

> This number is even or this number is odd.
>   This number is not even.
>   Therefore, this number is odd.
>    "...... logic confusing.
>    My mind is not shot.
>   Therefore,.......”)

Comment: To be "shot" is slang, and it means to be malfunctioning and unrepairable.  "This old engine is shot."

Comment: Where did you get the "with gun" part? I don't think it is related to this usage.

Comment: @user3169 - The “with gun” part came with the translation. I can see how a translation tool would assume _shot_ means _gunshot_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"[Someone's] mind is shot" means their mental capabilities are impaired. It's mostly used when people are fatigued or describing the effects of old age. It could be used to describe the effects of habitual drinking or drug use, but isn't usually used to describe the immediate effects of being drunk or drugged.

"[Someone's] mind is not shot" means someone thinks they are not affected by such a condition.